# Services are stuck and error in WFE server

Tags: 2010, sharepoint-server

HI i get the following error in one of WFE server in sharepoint 2010 farm,
and

> Claims to Windows Token Service
>   Microsoft SharePoint Foundation Web
>   Application  Search Query and Site Settings Service
>    The Execute
>   method of job definition
>   Microsoft.Office.Server.Search.Monitoring.TraceDiagnosticsProvider (ID
>   6725ef52-3ce4-48dc-8927-3cb5a74ef152) threw an exception.  More
>   information is included below.

Cannot open database "WSS_UsageApplication" requested by the login. The login failed.
Login failed for user 'xxx\spfarm'.

Spfarm user has db_owner for wss_usageapplication db.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to make sure that you are checking the right Content database on right server.

From `central admin > Monitoring > Configure usage and health data collection >`  on this page, scroll down until the Logging Database Server's Section and check the SQL server name and Database name. Now check the permission on it for the account.

also check if the database is online at sql server.

are you sharing the SQL with multiple farms? sometime we have multiple usage databases.